# How to create a HashMap from a text document and show specific keys and value

Tags: java, dictionary, hashmap

I am trying to create a simple method that will read a text file with a few lines of text separated by commas and split the text after the first comma into a key then every other comma until a new line into the value for that key.

Steps:

1. Read File from `ourFilePath`
2. Split the first word in each line (`DataEntry1`) into a Key then everything after the first comma into the Value for that Key.
3. After Search the Keys for the Key I am looking for and print out the Value of that key.

Example:

filetest.txt:

```
DataEntry1, Important, Stuff, Data, Clouds
DataEntry2, Boring, Stuff, Numbers, Cats
DataEntry3, Strange, Stuff, MoreData, Dogs
```

Code:

```
public static void getOurData(String ourFilePath, String ourDataName) throws Exception {
    Map<String, String> ourMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(ourFilePath));
    String line = "";

    while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
        String parts[] = line.split(",", 2);

        ourMap.put(parts[1], parts[0]);
        System.out.println(ourMap.toString());
    }

    in.close();
```

So far I only have the reading from a file working, I am trying to figure out how to make each of the `DataEntry` into a Key for the HashMap `ourMap` and everything after into a Value for it as well.

After that I am positive  I can finish Step 3 to search the Map for a specific key and print out that value.

Comment: ~~What exactly is not working here? At first glance the code seems ok.~~ Yay, swapped key and value, indeed :)

Comment: If DataEntryX is always the first element on a line, then all you need to do is split the line by comma and then remove spaces. With the split, use split[0] to get the data entry. This will be your key. The value is just everything after it. For this, you could build your string back up from the split[1] to split[length - 1], or re-split the original string.

Comment: It's `Map.put(key, value)`.  You appear to be swapping the arguments.

Comment: Ahh I see the swap, thanks! @JohnBollinger

Comment: @Jacob Ill look into using that as my split.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's seems ok, you need only to change the order of the argument when you call

```
ourMap.put(key, value);
```

try

```
while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
    String parts[] = line.split(",", 2);

    ourMap.put(parts[0], parts[1]); // change here
    System.out.println(ourMap.toString());
}
```

Comment: Yup @JohnBollinger stated that too. Rookie mistake :) Thank you!